# iOS Navigation Bar title not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Say in DogViewController which is the root view controller of a navigation controller in a storyboard I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (someConditionWhereIWantCatInsteadOfDog) {
        CatViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Cat"];
        self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[vc];

        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in CatViewController I have this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.title = @"Cat"; //this definitely gets called, but has no effect
}
```

However the title remains "Dog" in the nav bar. Why is this? Is there a better way to replace the root view controller so that I can get the correct title in the nav bar?

Comment: try self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"hai";

Comment: when u say self.title it is referring to UIViewController but not UINavigationViewController. So you should use self.navigationController.navigationItem.title.

Comment: If your viewController has a navigationBarController as you mentioned it should be working. Have you tried it in the viewDidLoad? And I would present it like this: [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a problem with your in this part of your code

```
 if (someConditionWhereIWantCatInsteadOfDog) {
    CatViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Cat"];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[vc];

    return;
}
```

to assign controller you have either to push it

```
if (someConditionWhereIWantCatInsteadOfDog) {
    CatViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Cat"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];

    return;
}
```

or assign the root view controller in storyboard
[See image in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqIla.png)